# cxf-bundle vs cxf-bundle-jaxrs

Tags: java, cxf, cxf-client

I want to know about [cxf-bundle](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle) and [cxf-bundle-jaxrs](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-jaxrs) jars. Are they 2 different jars, or former itself includes the latter?

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former includes the latter.

However, you shouldn't really use either as they no longer exist with CXF 3.x.  Using the individual jars that implement the specific functionality you need is the recommended approach.